# Can't seem to do a Function.Invoke with multiple parameters in powershell?

Tags: function, powershell, arguments, parameter-passing, invoke-command

I'm trying to pass a function to a method and then pass parameters to the method I passed when calling it, but if I pass more than one parameter then the method fails with an error:

```
function debugMeStuffs($someBlah, $somePoo) {

    Write-Host $someBlah            
    Write-Host $somePoo
}


function invokeOnHosts ([scriptblock]$funcToCall, $param1, $param2, $startRange, $endRange) {
#Param($funcToCall)

$i = $startRange

for($i = [int]$startRange; $i -le $endRange; $i++) {

    # HOW DO I MAKE THIS WORK WITH MULTIPLE PARAMETERS?!?!?!?
    $funcToCall.Invoke('blah' 'poo')
}
}

invokeOnHosts $function:debugMeStuffs "param1" "param2" 4 7
```

Things I've tried:

- `$funcToCall("blah" "poo")`
- `$funcToCall('blah' 'poo')`
- `$funcToCall.Invoke("blah" "poo")`
- `$funcToCall.Invoke('blah' 'poo')`
- `$funcToCall 'blah' 'poo'`
- `$funcToCall.Invoke 'blah' 'poo'`
- `$funcToCall "blah" "poo"`
- `$funcToCall.Invoke "blah" "poo"`

None of the above seem to work.  Is there something else I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Invoke()` is a .NET *method*, so the usual **method-call syntax applies**: you need

- parentheses - `(...)` - around the list of arguments
- you must separate the arguments with `,`

```
$funcToCall.Invoke('blah', 'poo')
```

---

This contrasts with **PowerShell's own syntax for calling *cmdlets* and *functions***, which is ***shell-like***<sup>[1]</sup>:

- *no* `(...)` around the argument list
- arguments must be separated with *spaces*.

```
& $funcToCall blah poo  # equivalent of the method call above.
```

A command such as the above is parsed in [*argument* mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), which is why *quoting* the arguments in this simple case is *optional*.

Note the need for `&`, PowerShell's [*call operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#special-operators), which is needed to *execute* the *script block* stored in `$funcToCall`; this is generally necessary for invoking a command stored in a *variable*, and also for command names / paths that are *quoted*.

---

**Given that it's easy to get confused between PowerShell's command syntax and .NET's method syntax, it's *best to stick with PowerShell-native features*<sup>[2]</sup>, if possible.**
That said, being able to call methods on .NET types directly is a wonderful extensibility option.

To help avoid accidental use of method syntax when calling PowerShell commands, you can use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note that that entails additional strictness checks.

---

[1] PowerShell is, after all, a *shell* - but it is *also* a *full-featured scripting language* that offers near-unlimited access to the .NET framework.
Reconciling these two personalities is a difficult balancing act, and the shell-like command-invocation syntax is a frequent problem for newcomers with a programming background, given that the rest of the language looks like a traditional programming language and that calling methods on .NET types *does* use the traditional syntax.

[2] This means preferring PowerShell's cmdlets, functions, and [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) to use of the underlying .NET types' methods; doing so also usually provides rewards you with operating at a higher level of abstraction.